# Are French hotels currently prohibited from using air conditioning?

Tags: france, hotels, regulations, covid-19

We just arrived at a 4-star hotel in France that says they are not allowed to have air-conditioning because of new Regulations.  We are aware of regulations that affect restaurants, but this is the first time we have heard that they can't or won't turn on the AC.

Is this new?  Did it go into effect when they reinstated the Face Mask Law?  We think they're fibbing, but thought prudent to research.

Unfortunately for us, we did not read the online information properly.  It doesn't say anything about not being able to use AC.  They sprung that on us after we checked in.

And unfortunately for them, we've stayed in hotels all across France the last two weeks where, guess what, they had AC.

Comment: Could it depend on the type of AC system they have?

Comment: [This article](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/sante/maladie/coronavirus/coronavirus-pas-de-risque-majeur-d-infection-a-utiliser-un-climatiseur-estime-sante-publique-france_4053131.html) (in French) says that Santé Publique France published a study today saying that it was not a major risk, so long as proper filters are in place and the air is frequently circulated.  But this may not be possible in your hotel's particular AC system.  (I'd link directly to the SPF report, but I can't seem to find it on their website;  maybe it will appear in a day or two?)

Comment: I read the title of this question as "Have been told that French Hotels are NOT Allowed to use Alternating Current" and was mightily confused.

Comment: I was wondering what AC was. Such abbreviations should be 'introduced' for those not familiar with them: Air Conditioning (AC)

Comment: I don’t think there is anything dictated by the authorities that would prevent the use of AC at this time. However, there have been quite a few doubts on the impact of AC in spreading the virus, and it is possible some hotels or hotel brands may have decided to err on the side of caution. Maybe when they say “we are not allowed” they mean “the hotel chain does not allow us to”. There may also be differences based on the AC setup.

Comment: @Marc Parsont I doubt anyone on TSE can answer this definitively. I suggest you ask the hotel to show you the relevant prohibition(s) on using AC

Comment: I've also *heard of* regulations about using AC because of its electricity usage.

Comment: https://solidarites-sante.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/covid-19-aeration-ventilation-climatisation.pdf does not prohibit use of air conditioning. It is from French health minister.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.